# Feed import of CSV file only in imports the title and nothing else. It also has paragraph fields

Tags: 7, feeds, importing-exporting, paragraphs

I'm trying to import a small subset of my data to test out how well it would go first before importing 20k records. I'm using the latest feeds module with the paragraphs feeds importer (https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/shaney/2862236). For now I'm only importing:

- guid
- title
- field_client
- field_award_status (paragraph field under"award")
- field_award_name (paragraph field under "award")

The only successful import is the title, but nothing else shows up. Below is a preview of my csv data and my feed mapping settings. What could I be missing?

[image]

Comment: Are these all text fields? (In manage display, the field type = Text field? )

Comment: yes they are all text fields and some are taxonomy reference fields. the ones in the paragraphs is also text and taxonomy references.

Answer (score 1):

I checked the csv file in an editor it found the culprit was because I deleted a bunch of records using excel and it left alot of empty commas everywhere. You have to go into the csv file and edit it manually.

Also it wasn't importing because the values need to be in quotes.